# How to organise file structure of backend and frontend in MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

I have backend based on express + mongoose. File structure is:

```
- /models
-- item.js
- /node.modules
-- ...
- server.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
```

And regular create-react-app based folder for front-end:

```
- /src
-- /assets
--- index.css
-- /components
--- Somecomponent.js
-- /containers
--- App.js
-- /reducers
--- somereducers.js
- /node.modules
-- ...
-- index.js
-- registerServiceWorker.js
- .gitignore
- package-lock.json
- package.json
```

I want to use it in proper way together. I wanted to organise it this way:

```
- /client 
-- /src
...
-- index.js
-- registerServiceWorker.js
- .gitignore
- package-lock.json
- package.json

- /server
- /models
-- item.js
- /node.modules
-- ...
- server.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
```

At this stage I stuck. I can make it if client folder inside server folder or if server folder inside client. 
1. But how to make it run when two folders are siblings? 
2. What should be package.json and where node.modules should be (whether both server and client should have it's own package.json and modules?)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The most basic structure would be to have a `root` folder that contains `frontend` and `backend` folders. Since you're talking about the ***MERN*** stack, you would have a `package.json` inside of your **`NodeJS`** backend environment and a `package.json` for your **`React`** side of things. Backend server and the frontend client are two totally separate things, so yes, they both have their own node_modules folders. On the backend, you'll probably have installed something like `Express` for your Node runtime, `Mongoose` for a more convenient way to talk to your `MongoDB`, etc, and on your frontend, you'll have your `React`  as your frontend framework, `Redux` for state management, etc. Additionally, depending on what you have already listed inside of your package.json files, when you run `npm install` **separately** it will be installed in those two folders. If you want to install additional packages, just run `npm install + "the name of the package"` (without the '+' and without the quotes) inside of that particular folder where you need it (backend or/ and frontend).

I hope this was helpful. Check out the pics, especially the 2nd one.

**App structure**
 [image]

**Folder structure**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In development, I suggest installing two additional things:

1. *`npm i -D nodemon`*
2. *`npm i -D concurrently`*

Note: The `-D` flag will install them as *`devDependencies`*.

**`nodemon`** is going to track every file change and restart the backend server for you. So, it's obvious that it should be installed inside of the "backend" folder. All you have to do is go inside of the `package.json` file (backend) and add a new script. Something like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js",  // in production
"dev": "nodemon app.js", // in development
}
```

---

**`concurrently`** allows you to start both your frontend and backend at the same time. I suggest initializing a new Node project inside of the top-level **root** folder -[folder which contains both, your frontend and backend]. You would do that with the `npm init` command, and after that, install the `concurrently` package there.

Now, go open your newly created `package.json` file inside of your ***root*** folder and edit the start section, like this:

```
   "scripts": {
       "dev": "concurrently \"cd backend && npm run dev\" \"cd frontend && npm start\" "
   }
```

What this will do is go inside of the **backend** folder and run the `dev` command (*the same one we just configured*), so that will start `nodemon`. Additionally, it will also go inside of the **frontend** folder and run the default `start` command -which is exactly what we want.

If you kept the folder structure, installed all the dependencies (including the additional two I mentioned above), changed the `package.json` file inside of your **`root`** folder, you'll be able to start them both with a simple command:

**`npm run dev`** // make sure you're inside of the root folder when doing so :)

Comment: That's was very helpful. How to run both backend and frontend with one `npm start` command?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my previous answer with that info, and if that's helpful too, please accept my answer ;)

Comment: Completely off topic, but what IDE/theme is that folder structure screenshot?

Comment: @Icode4food  Editor: **VS Code** with a **Custome theme** (meaning I made it myself changing the user preferences). You can do it also by hitting **CTRL + P**, in the search box enter `> Preferences: Open user settings` and edit the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations, workbench.colorCustomizations` and everything else you might want to customize to fit your needs. I have a lot of it :) ... and btw for the icons, I'm using the **material-icon-theme**. If you want to avoid all that I suggest, installing a theme called **One Dark Pro Monokai Darker**. It's kinda similar to what I got. Cheers **;)**

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I work in Vue, but it looks like the architecture will translate.

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman The pleasure is all mine. Trust me.  By the end of the day, it's all `JavaScript`, right? -So, it doesn't really matter is it React, Angular or Vue It's all about the architecture and scalability.  Have a good one ;)

Comment: @Bigga_HD, would you recommend having the root folder uploaded to a single GitHub repo or two separate ones?

Comment: Definitely one repo. Good luck ;) @Otto Gutierrez

Comment: I'm really new to MERN. Could you please tell me how would the backend interact with the built files in the frontend folder? Or does it do something else?

Comment: @Sapinder You can either run them separately or you could copy the [build files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to a folder on the server (e.g. 'public') which you would then expose via the [static method](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). There's also [SSR](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html), but it is a bit more advanced topic. I would go for the second option. So, there's your answer `How do they interact?` -> By sending the appropriate HTTP request from the client to the appropriate endpoint on the server and vice versa.

Comment: @DzenisH. Your answer helped me a lot. I have 1 question, instead of using concurrently in the `package.json` at root directory, I simply used the script: `"install": "(cd backend && npm install) & (cd frontend && npm install)"`. So it this also acceptable or can there be some potential issues with it ?
I have similar script for running: `"dev": "(cd backend && npm run start) & (cd frontend && npm run start)"`

Comment: @HarshitTrehan That's fine, I guess. However, it can get hard to keep track of different outputs. Additionally, if one process fails (for whatever reason), others still keep running, and you won't even notice the difference (until it's too late and you're pissed) :) That's just my two cents. Anyways, keep up the good work, and I'm thrilled that my answer was helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't think of that scenario. I already had quite a lot of dependencies for my MERN project so I figured maybe not to use concurrently, but since its just a dev dependency I guess its okay. Thanks again. Cheers :)

Comment: This works well in development. But how do you deploy a mern stack app with such a file structure to a platform like digital ocean where am using the digital ocean new app platform?

Comment: @Dijiflex The question is not about deployment. There's not a single mention of it in the original question. There are many different ways to deploy a MERN app. May I suggest posting a SO question and linking it to a comment below? Have a good one.

Comment: very insightful, In my case .gitignore exist on root level of backend, I will be dragging a react them in, do I have to keep another .gitignore in `client`aka `frontend` folder ? or uses same root level .gitingore for both

Comment: @MuhammadUzair It all depends how you want to push your code. If you want to push it all (backend and fronted) then have a single. gitignore file at the root level, but if you want to separate FE from BE you would have 2 of those files, on for FE and another one for BE.

Comment: So how do you deploy this so that Express serves the React frontend? Do you use `../../` in the path to get to the sibling folder?

Comment: @FlorianWalther No, you deploy the FE from the BE separately

Answer (score 26):

Adding to the accepted answer, the folder structure division inside the frontend and backend is more useful if it is based on business logic rather than tech logic.

Dividing the whole stack into self-contained components that preferably don't share files among them is the best way to make your app more testable and easy to update. This in the smallest possible way is what commonly known as microservice architecture.

***Bad Design : difficult to update and test***:
[image: Bad Design for folder structure]

***Good Design : easy to update and test***:

[image: Good Design for folder structure]

Comment: This answer interests me, but I feel that it lacks justification. Could you explain it a little better for a newbie like me?

Comment: This is kind of  based on django file structure which i have found easier to test and update.  Each bussiness component is one "app". 

Seperating based on bussiness logic rather than keeping same type (classes) together is easier to maintian in a larger team, imho. Refactoring becomes easier, seperation of concerns is more clearly defined and domain boundaries are more clearly defined.

Comment: I'm actually interested about this answer too. I've learned to do it the "bad way" but now seeing your answer I like your suggestion a lot. My question is:  You mention that is somehow used in microservices architecture? Do you have some reference where we can read fruther? Tahnks!

Comment: Rarely in my career have I ever found a business domain with this kind of clear separation. Do you duplicate the product.js in the orders folder? Leave out FK in data structure between products and orders? If not, it's not a microservice, though many companies call it that and then struggle to figure out why they're having so much trouble.

And, I would expect my junior developers to be regularly referencing "layers" incorrectly if I structured my team's code this way. I were the only coder and I didn't expect anyone else to support it, I might consider this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use Structure as per your requirement, like based on the project scope or depth. But make sure to keep the endpoints and models separate, so initially have a setup like such

```
src/
controllers - for the endpoints
models - for the schema
server.js - or index.js
```