# React + backend - project structure when sharing code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I really like the folder structure as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126472/how-to-organise-file-structure-of-backend-and-frontend-in-mern/51128385#51128385) when dealing with a React frontend and a some backend with express:

```
root
├── backend
|   ├── node_modules
|   ├── public
|   ├── src
│   │   └── Server.ts
|   ├── package.json
|   └── tsconfig.json
├── frontend (created using create-react-app)
|   ├── node_modules
|   ├── public
|   ├── src
│   │   └── Index.js
|   ├── package.json
|   └── tsconfig.json
```

I think that having separate packages with individual `node_modules` is reasonable since the frontend and backend are basically completely different things, e. g. they need different node modules. Also, this modular approach is visually appealing to me and the repository looks tidy.

---

However, I encounter a problem with this structure when I need to share content between the frontend and the backend. I added a `shared` folder under the root-of-project which contains its own project with its own `tsconfig.json`, `package.json` and so on. This approach is a mix of the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58845129/9655481) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428140/9655481). For the backend, this works totally fine: having set up the `tsconfig.json` appropriately (using [TypeScript Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#what-is-a-project-reference) and [aliased imports](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353)), I can reference the file `root/shared/src/myFile.ts` like this:

```js
import { myFunction } from @shared/myFile;
```

**I created the React frontend using `create-react-app`**. It's ok for me that alias imports don't work, so I would have to use (inside the src folder in frontend):

```js
import { myFunction } from '../../shared/src/myFile';
```

**Sadly, these imports from outside the `src` directory [are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory/44115058) by `create-react-app` and I don't want to use `eject`** since I have no experience with webpack and don't want to maintain all the configuration files on my own (that's why I used `create-react-app` in the first place).

---

I know I can move the shared content to the frontend's `src` directory. But this would mean, I had to add the tags needed for using [Project References in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#what-is-a-project-reference), e. g. setting `composite` to true, in the frontend's `tsconfig.json` which seems odd to me and feels more like a hack. I'd like to have a separate npm project with my shared content.

Since `create-react-app` does not inherently support imports from outside the `src` directory, I thought that maybe I'm getting the big picture wrong. Isn't the folder structure I use right now a valid way of how to setup a React project with a backend? What mechanism does `create-react-app` provide to link files between the frontend and the backend? I could also think of having a root project with a `src` folder and inside of that the two folders `backend` and `frontend`. But this means, that we'd have one shared `node_modules` folder in root.

It's my first project with React and I'd love to get to know some **best practicese for this kind of architectural problem**. Some links to trustful resources where project structures for full-stack React development are explained would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: As someone who's spent 650+ hrs maintaining the isomorphic parts of our product; (SSR, Shared Code, utilites etc) I can tell you now the best way to do it is to ditch CRA and convert to next.js + typescript + in-built /pages/api for your server.

Your frontend and backend will converge into a single project that is 100x more maintainable

Answer (score 10):

It's perfectly reasonable to want to share code between your front and back end. It's one of the reasons to code in javascript instead of Ruby or PHP.

You can accomplish exactly what you want by using yarn instead of npm and   yarn workspaces: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/.  At the top level you set up three modules/packages in your package.json (make sure you name the workspaces correctly in their respective package.json files):

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
        "backend",
        "frontend",
        "shared"
    ]
},
```

Once you do, you can import shared code in your CRA app or your back end simply like this:

```
import { myFunction } from 'shared/src/myFile';
```

The drawback is that you can't import react components from the **shared** directory into **frontend** as long as you are using CRA. This won't affect you now since you only have one react app. Should you need to share react components among multiple projects, look into some on the suggestions above like bit.dev.

ADDENDUM!!! It's now possible to use CRA and yarn workspaces to share React code, if you replace CRA with [CRACO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco).  All you do is create another workspace with the shared react code. Then create a symbolic link in each module where you want to access it:

```
root
├── fontend-one
|   ├── symbolic link to frontend-shared
├── frontend-two
|   ├── symbolic link to frontend-shared
├── frontend-shared
```

Each of the CRA front end modules modules also requires a craco.config.js file where you tell web-pack not to follow symbolic links:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            resolve: {
                symlinks: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You import from shared-frontend normally:

```
import { myFunction } from 'shared-frontend/src/myFile';
```

It's a pretty lo-fi solution but has proven robust for the year we've been using it.

Comment: How would you go about hosting a full-stack project that has a shared folder?

Comment: Nothing special is needed to share code between the front and back end.  Just use yarn workspaces and import from the shared workspace.

Comment: Yea, but when I host the project, I host the back end and front end separately.

If I have a shared folder that is used by both the back end and the front end, how would I have this folder be available to the fe and be in prod.

Would I perhaps host the shared folder somehow along with the fe and be during the deployment process.

Comment: Search on monrepo.  Keep all your code in the same repository and deploy separately or put your shared code in a npm package or a shared github repo.

Comment: I think I found my answer with some help from you:

Host Shared Folder During Deployment:

    If you prefer to keep the shared code together with the deployed applications, you can include the shared folder during the deployment process.
    For example, when deploying the front end, ensure that the shared folder is part of the deployment package.
    Similarly, when deploying the back end, include the shared folder in the deployment package.

Answer (score 6):

Architecture is a tricky one, everyone has a different opinion and every option has pro and cons.

Personally I believe its best to separate the backend and frontend into sperate projects and keep them that way. Now as JavaScript/React/Node encourage component-based approaches a really nice way of sharing code between them is Bit.dev.

https://bit.dev

I am currently using it to share components and functions between three web apps and a few Node microservices.

A good structure for React app can be found here, this one works well and scales nicely:

https://hackernoon.com/fractal-a-react-app-structure-for-infinite-scale-4dab943092af

As for Express, there are so many ways to structure the project but personally recommend a folder for your Routes, a folder for your Controllers, this is where the logic for Routes live. Then go from there. Check this link out:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-production-ready-node-and-express-app-f214f0b17d8c/

Depending on what your building you may not even need a full backend you can check out the JAMStack here for more info:

https://jamstack.org

I would consider separating them though as the project scales it makes it much easier to manage. You can release your front end on something like Netlify and then use something like AWS or Azure to host your Node/Express server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Having separate sub-projects for frontend and backend makes perfect sense due to vastly different dependencies. Mixing it up increases disk space consumption in production deployments and goes against security guidelines. Your folder structure is reasonable (except for `public/` subfolders I'm unsure about, maybe I'm missing something).
2. The approach `import { myFunction } from @shared/myFile;` is fine. Just don't use CRA.
3. For a project with a single frontend and a single backend there is no need for a `shared\` top-level folder because the frontend is the only source of 'UI truth' (e.g. the source of types and components related to UI) that is consumed by the frontend and the backend is the only source of 'API truth' consumed by both frontend and backend. With this arrangement only `@backend/api_shared_stuff` needs to be shared.
4. *Some links to trustful resources where project structures for full-stack React development are explained would be really helpful.* On the one hand, usually project authors have to explain plenty of other things and on the other hand keep the documentation (typically a README) reasonably concise. You may find that providing a justification/explanation why the subdirectory structure is this and not that was not the top priority.