# Typescript project references: Handle third-party dependencies of referenced project

Tags: typescript, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a project with 3 directories `client`, `api`, and `shared`. The `shared` directory contains typescript types and definitions inside an `engine` folder that I would like to share with `client` and `api`. Additionally, the `shared` directory requires some third party dependencies as well (specified in its package.json file).

A very basic sample repository describing this scenario can be found [here](https://github.com/priyath/typescript-shared-example/tree/project-references), under the branch `project-references`. Essentially, `server.js` in `api` will import and call a function from the `Entity.ts` class which in turn, relies on an external library (mathjs).

Now I have been trying to use project references (rather unsuccessfully!) to build my `api` (I have not looked into the client yet!) so that the shared code will be available in a `dist` folder within the `api` for use.

**What I have done so far:**

1. I have added the following `tsconfig.build-api.json` file to `shared` directory. The `outDir` points to a `dist` folder inside `api`. The idea is to move the compiled shared files to the api's `dist` folder, maintaining the same directory structure in `dist` so that my imports won't break. Similarly, I plan on having another tsconfig file for the client.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../api/dist/shared"
  },
  "include": ["engine"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"],
  "references": []
}
```

2. I have updated the api's `tsconfig.json` file to reference the shared directory's `tsconfig.build-api.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // some options
    "outDir": "dist/api/src",
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../shared/tsconfig.build-api.json" }
  ],
  // some more options
}
```

3. I run `tsc --build .` from inside the `api` directory which creates a `dist` folder with the compiled api and shared code in it. However, when I try to run this built code, I get an error stating that the third party dependencies of the `shared` code cannot be found.

How can I make sure the third party dependencies of my referenced project (`shared`) are resolved without any issues inside `api`?

Note: Without the third party dependencies in my shared code, I could get all of this working without project references by just using relative paths to do the required imports. Thiw was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031698/my-approach-to-share-typescript-code-between-cra-and-backend-am-i-missing-anyth). However, with the external dependencies, I still cannot figure out a way to do this. Research has led to things like monorepositories, learna, yarn workspaces etc etc. But I would like to think this can be solved without relying on external tooling.

Comment: Hello @fsociety, did you find a good way to do this? I'm struggling with a similar problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002116/sharing-a-typescript-library-in-a-monorepo

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem and with several days of head scratching and using whatever I could find online, this is the only solution that I think will work properly. It's rather fragile, in the sense that it needs a very carefully balanced folder structure to work.

I'll use the client-server-common paradigm for the discussion, both the *client* and the *server* depending on the *common* project. Let's start with the topmost, "solution" folder.

Apart from other settings, it needs a `tsconfig.json` with (to make sure TSC builds both dependent projects):

```
"references": [
  {
    "path": "./client"
  },
  {
    "path": "./server"
  },
 ]
```

And a `package.json` with (to make sure the running code will be able to load the common module):

```
"imports": {
  "#common/foobar": "./out/common/src/foobar.js"
},
```

Both the *client* and the *server* packages need a `tsconfig` with -- to make sure that they get output to a common `out` folder, to help TS (IDE) to find the common module and to depend on it for the build process:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "rootDir": "../",
  "outDir": "../out",
  "paths": {
    "#common/*": [
      "../common/src/*.ts"
    ]
  },
},
"references": [
  {
    "path": "../common"
  }
],
```

Both projects can use and refer to the *common* in their source code as:

```
import { foobar } from '#common/foobar';
```

The *common* project needs a `tsconfig` with (also to output to the same folder, and to act as an appropriate `TSC --build` dependent project):

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "rootDir": "../",
  "outDir": "../out",
  "composite": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "declarationMap": true,
},
"references": []
```

The end result is a common `out` in the project topmost folder, with subfolders for each of the three subprojects. You can go on with packing if needed from there.

I found that if the `outDir` or `rootDir` folders have any other structure, even if that comes from the official documentation, the whole scheme falls apart. The biggest hurdle to overcome was that we would need both the source (the compiler and the analysis tools in the IDE) and the final, transpiled code to resolve the *common* module. While we use the same `#common/foobar` notation in both cases, the two have different underlying mechanisms: the toolchain uses `tsconfig.json` while the running code uses `package.json`. And while the first allows us to look outside the project folder root (with `../`), the second **does not**. That's why I said you needed to accept this `out/*` structure as is, and modify your packaging or running needs to suit this folder structure, not the other way around: `out` with the three subfolders will work, while three subfolders with each with its `out` will not.

And finally, don't forget to call TSC in its build mode:

```
"scripts": {
  "compile": "tsc -b",
```

External dependencies are left for the specific case, each subproject needs its own dependencies and the topmost `package.json` will also need the relevant packages in its `node_modules`.