# Sharing a typescript library in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, npm, monorepo

I'm trying to setup a monorepo with 3 services sharing some library code.

This is the current situation:

```
repo: web
pdf/
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts using github url
  tsconfig.json
frontend/
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts using github url
  tsconfig.json
```

```
repo: mobile (react-native)
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts using github url
  tsconfig.json
```

```
repo: shared-ts
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

This works but it's a pain to commit to `shared-ts`, build, change the hash in `package.json` and commit again.

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```
repo: monorepo
pdf/
  package.json
    reference to ../shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
frontend/
  package.json
    reference to ../shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
mobile/
  package.json
    reference to ../shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
shared-ts/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

So far I've tried:

- TypeScript project references, but it seems like there is no way to have dependencies in the shared-ts project
- `"shared-ts": "../shared-ts"` in package.json but it copies shared-ts into the node_modules of each package so I have to re-run yarn everytime I make a change
- `yarn link` in `postinstall`: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'shared-ts' or its corresponding type declarations.`
- creating a symlink directly in `postinstall` with `ln -s ../shared-ts/ node_modules/shared-ts/` but it seems TypeScript fails to find the module
- `npm link` in `postinstall` seems like the most promising but it's really slow and I'm having trouble running it in CI because of some permissions issues.

Is there a good way of doing this? Any ideas on other things I could try?

Comment: are you using Linux ? maybe a shell script can help

Comment: This is what workspaces and lerna are for. Very common.

Answer (score 7):

## Solution 1:

### with Lerna

you can use workspace and Lerna

```
yarn workspace & lerna
```

```
├── README.md
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── pdf
│   │   ├── package.json   /*  "shared-ts": "^1.0.0" */
│   │   └──  src
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── src
│   ├── mobile
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── src
│   ├── shared-ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └──  src
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

here is an example [repo](https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example)

here you can see [x-cli](https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example/blob/2381ad99cf3967eb2c2f57eb330ee665bc601a74/packages/x-cli/package.json#L13) is getting shared [x-core](https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example/blob/2381ad99cf3967eb2c2f57eb330ee665bc601a74/packages/x-core/package.json#L2)

## Solution 2:

### without Lerna

you can use [mtsl](https://github.com/nomi9995/mtsl) package which enables us to make tangible symlinks. you can install this package globally

```
npm install -g mtsl
```

then you just need to start to separate these three commands in terminal.

```sh
mtsl startwithoutadd -s path_of_project/packages/shared-ts -d path_of_project/packages/pdf/node_modules/shared-ts

mtsl startwithoutadd -s path_of_project/packages/shared-ts -d path_of_project/packages/frontend/node_modules/shared-ts

mtsl startwithoutadd -s path_of_project/packages/shared-ts -d path_of_project/packages/mobile/node_modules/shared-ts
```

**Note** don't stop this three watcher. after testing, you can make single command from the `package.json` script

Answer (score 6):

Your use-case can be handled using the [npm7 workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces). In short your new monorepo structure should look like below:

```
repo: monorepo
package.json // <- here you define the workspaces
pdf/
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
frontend/
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
mobile/
  package.json
    reference to shared-ts
  tsconfig.json
shared-ts/
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

You need to list the workspaces in the root `package.json` which might look something like below:

```json
{
  "name": "awesome-monorepo",
  "workspaces": [
    "pdf",
    "frontend",
    "mobile",
    "shared-ts"
  ]
}
```

After doing that, wherever in the monorepo you decide to use the `shared-ts` you can add that to `dependencies` or `devDependencies` simply referring by the version number instead of relative path.

All the node modules inclusive the workspaces gets hoisted to the root `node_modules` which is why the module resolution should work without friction.

Answer (score -1):

I have done the things you are curious about in a recent project.
Desired results can be achieved by monorepo using lerna and yarn workspace. For details, please go to this [link](https://blog.kintone.io/entry/2020/07/14/103322)

With the above, we will be creating a package of types.
In other packages, we will be just importing types from packages like below:

```
import { Post } from "@types";
```

Things are much easier this way than linking packages ourslef.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [NX](https://nx.dev/) to maintain your repos, wherein your `web` and `mobile` repos will be your apps, and the `shared-ts` will be a lib such that, `web` and `mobile` depends on `shared-ts` lib.

You have a common package.json, or a separate package.json for each repo individually. NX provides `dependencyGraph` and `affected` features, wherein if you change the common libs, it figures out which modules/app to build without having to build the complete thing.

Your code structure would look like:

```
apps:
  web:
    src
    package.json

  mobile:
    src
    package.json

libs:
   shared-ts:
     src
     package.json

workspace.json
```

It'll probably be best to lookup the official docs for the best setup and options, but I believe it provides what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

using `yarn workspace & lerna`

here is an example [monorepo-template](https://github.com/LiuL0703/monorepo-template)