# best structure for MERN stack web App (nodejs & express & mongoDB as a server and Reactjs as a Client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I have a MERN stack app whats the best structure for it? take in account i will use the express API later for a Mobile application
i have this structure now (main folder App inside it Client and server folder every folder has it own node_modules folder package.json and package-lock.json or should i have only one node_modules folder package.json and package-lock.json for both in the main App? and how to push them to Heroku should i push every app separately or both together as a one app and how?

Answer (score 1):

If you going for then `mono-repo` (single git repository for the whole project) approach its a good practice to keep modules separate. Each one with its own dependencies.

The most common solution is a top-level `tooling` mechanism that keeps each module separated but still have the ability to install and build all the projects.
Many developers are using [`lerna`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage multiple node projects.

Answer (score 0):

Two seperate 'Backend' and 'Frontend' folders inside a 'root' folder. Those two folders should have their own seperate 'node_modules' folder and 'package.json'. [Here's a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128385/13995125)