# Should I make multiple node_modules folders for multiple files or use one?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am starting a JavaScript project and its parent directory contains 2 folders: `client` and `server`. Both of these will require Javascript packages but I'm confused as to whether I should make a `node_modules` folder in each of them for their respective dependencies or whether I should create only one and install all the packages there. Basically what I'm asking is whether I should do this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should make a node_modules folder in each of them for their
> respective dependencies or whether I should create only one and
> install all the packages there.

As you have `client`- Frontend and `server` - Backend which are two different side of things and they will have their own dependencies with `package.json`. You might be installing some specific packages which only works on browser and same for server-side environment.

It is good to segregate both the environment to keep dependencies separate. You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126472/how-to-organise-file-structure-of-backend-and-frontend-in-mern) link to check out things in details.